# Angular material table change pagination format

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to implement an angular material table. I am able to show the table with data and pagination.

But currently the pagination format displaying is in the format below.

`Items per page 10    1- 10 of 20`

But I want the pagination format to be like this.

`Items per page 10  Range:  10/20`

Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ILUvaY?p=preview) URL.

Comment: Here's an example to get started: https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's worked.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a customIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl.You can replace lables of you own.

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';

export class CustomMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {

  getRangeLabel = function (page, pageSize, length) {
    if (length === 0 || pageSize === 0) {
      return '0/' + length;
    }
    length = Math.max(length, 0);
    const startIndex = page * pageSize;
    // If the start index exceeds the list length, do not try and fix the end index to the end.
    const endIndex = startIndex < length ?
      Math.min(startIndex + pageSize, length) :
      startIndex + pageSize;
    return endIndex + ' / ' + length;
  };
}
```

2.Add a customIntl to you module where you import the MatPaginator.

```
imports: [
       ...
       MatPaginatorModule,
],
providers: [
     ...
    {provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: CustomMatPaginatorIntl}
  ]
```